# Access an Object Array - System.NullReferenceException during runtime

Tags: c#, arrays, class, methods

I'm new in C# and have a Issue with my coding. I got an error during runtime. It's seems object array isn't assigned. Any help/hints are welcome. I have a class "Building" with fix rooms. No change or additional rooms are foreseens.
The rooms are discribed by a lots of attributes. In my "Home" class I want to access all in rooms via object array and also specific rooms.
Thanks in advance:

```
Class Home
{
private void StartProgramm()
        {

            //get all Objects of class "Building"
            Building[] building = Building.Buildings;

            //System.NullReferenceException during runtime

            set_label_header(building[0].Name);

            //Access to room1
            Building room1 = Building.room1;

            set_label_header(room1.Name);

            //Get room2
            Building room2 = Building.GetBuilding("room2");

            set_label_header(room2?.Name);



         }
}


    class Building
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ArrayList tool_groupList = new ArrayList();
        public ArrayList pos_List = new ArrayList();
        public ArrayList inv_list = new ArrayList();


        public static Building room1;
        public static Building room2;
        public static Building[] Buildings;


    public Building()
            {
            //create room 1 and add some attributes
            room1 = new Building { Name = "room1" };
            room1.tool_groupList.Add(1);
            room1.tool_groupList.Add(2);
            room1.pos_List.Add(14);
            room1.pos_List.Add(15);
            room1.pos_List.Add(16);
            room1.pos_List.Add(17);
            Iventory[] inventories = Inventory.get_inventories();
            room1.areaList.AddRange(inventories);



            //create room 2 and add some attributes
            room2 = new Building { Name = "room2" };
            room2.tool_groupList.Add(2);
            room2.pos_List.Add(1);
            room2.pos_List.Add(2);
            room2.pos_List.Add(9);
            room2.pos_List.Add(10);
            room2.pos_List.Add(13);
            room2.pos_List.Add(14);
            room2.pos_List.Add(15);
            room2.pos_List.Add(16);
            Iventory[] inventories = Inventory.get_inventories();
            room2.areaList.AddRange(inventories);


            //Array with all rooms
            Buildings = new Building[] { room1, room2 };


        }

        //get single room by name

        public static Building GetBuilding(string name)
        {
            foreach (Building Building in Buildings)
            {
               if( Building.Name != null && Building.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return Building;
                }

            }
            return null;
        }





    }
```

Comment: Can you help us by isolating the exact line where you get an error?

Comment: set_label_header(building[0].Name);

Comment: Ok, from that, my best guess is that `building` is null when you try to access `building[0]`. Since `building` doesn't exist, then it can't give you `building[0]`. Have you stepped over the code in debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the static field `Building.Buildings` before the constructor of the Class `Building` is called. After you create an instance of `Building` the static field would be assigned. You probably want to use a static constructor like in the following example:

```
static Building()
{
    ...
    Buildings = new Building[] { room1, room2 };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution